# Числа вывести в документ в виде нумерованного списка

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно вывести элементы массива, вводимого через функцию suma другой функцией Vivod, в список в сам html документ. Sum Работает корректно, массив есть. 
Код:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Практическая работа 5.4</title>
     <meta charset= "UTF-8">
     <script>
     function suma(){
     for (i=0; x !== 0; i++){
       x = parseInt(prompt("введите число:",''));
       numbers[i] = x;
       if (( x % 5 === 0) && (x === 5)) {sum += x;}
       if (x > 0) {pro *= x;}
     } 
     
    }
//вот тут ошибка, что не так?
     function Vivod(){
     var size;
     document.open();
     document.write("<ol>");
     for(size = 0; size < i-1; size ++){
     
     document.write("<li>"); 
     document.write(numbers[i]);
     document.write("</li>"); 
     }
     document.write("</ol>");
     document.close();
    }
     </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
     <script>
     var sum=0;
     var pro=1;
     var x=1;
     var i;
     var numbers = [];
     suma();
     </script>
     <table height=200 width=300 border="solid" cellspacing=1>
     <tr>
     <td>Сумма чисел, кратных 5: <script>document.write(sum)</script></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Произведение положительных чисел: <script>document.write(pro)</script></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <script>
     vivod();
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Что за переменная `myWindow`? Где она инициализируется?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ошибочка, я там кое-что проверял, там просто document.write. Щас поправлю. Но и так не работает

Comment: Уже лучше. У вас название функции - `Vivod`, а вызываете вы `vivod()`. Регистр имеет значение!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо, теперь он делает список, но в каждом пункте Undefined. Почему бы?

Comment: Может, `numbers[i]` заменить на `numbers[size]`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko  спасибо большое. Удалять не буду, вдруг какому-то неумехе, вроде меня пригодится)))

Comment: Да, удалять не надо! Лучше опубликуйте ответ в котором будет рабочий пример! Может, кому-то пригодится!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Полное условие задачи:**
Сложить числа кратные 5 и вычислить произведение положительных чисел. Ввод чисел должен быть завершен при наборе числа 0. Числа вывести в документ в виде нумерованного списка а результаты вычислений оформить в виде таблицы.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Практическая работа 5.4</title>
        <meta charset= "UTF-8">
        <script>
        function suma(){
        for (i=0; x !== 0; i++){
          x = parseInt(prompt("введите число:",''));
          numbers[i] = x;
          if (( x % 5 === 0) && (x === 5)) {sum += x;}
          if (x > 0) {pro *= x;}
        } 

    }
        function Vivod(){
        var size;
        document.open();
        document.write("<ol>");
        for(size = 0; size < i-1; size ++){
        document.write("<li>"); 
        document.write(numbers[size]);
        document.write("</li>");    
        }
        document.write("</ol>");
        document.close();
    }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <script>
        var sum=0;
        var pro=1;
        var x=1;
        var i;
        var numbers = [];
        suma();
        </script>
        <table height=200 width=300 border="solid" cellspacing=1>
        <tr>
        <td>Сумма чисел, кратных 5: <script>document.write(sum)</script></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Произведение положительных чисел: <script>document.write(pro)</script></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
        Vivod();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```